# Calling java SOAP web-Service from iPhone

Tags: iphone, web-services, wsdl

I have a query regarding calling java SOAP web-Service from iPhone.

I have successfully implemented calling .asmx type web services.
But I am getting following error when I try to implement same for WSDL.

Error Code: 407 Proxy Authentication Required. The ISA Server requires authorization to fulfill the request. Access to the Web Proxy filter is denied. (12209)

I am sending the correct SOAP Envelope 
and connecting to the url 
http://myWebService?WSDL

Is the problem related to web-service?
Or do I need to implement something else?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

WSDL is not a web service type, its an xml based description file. So that url is not the url of your webservice. Thus, you shouldnt send your requests to  `http://myWebService?WSDL`.

Try `http://myWebService/myservice.webserviceextension` ( asmx, svc, ...)